# What is the absolute secure way to transport/deliver information over the internet?

Tags: encryption, hash, digital-signature, internet

If I were to deliver data across the internet(From my LAN out into the nation's WAN) What would be the absolute secure way to do it? Would it be to use a digital signature with a symmetric key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One-Time Pad combined with Steganography, like this:

[image: Relax, folks, it's all fluff]

Of course, the challenge with OTP is key distribution.  But if you're thinking "nation" level, then there's usually a way to distribute One-Time Pads.

Strictly speaking, the Steganography adds very little once you're already using a OTP, but it is cute.

Comment: I get that it's supposed to just be an adorable picture, but all I can see in that kittens face is a look of pleading terror as the marshmallows slowly but surely suck the poor creature down and under.... forever.

Comment: @Numeron if you were to extract the ciphertext stream from the picture and successfully guess the OT Pad, you'd know *what* struck the terror into that poor kitten's heart... it *wasn't* the marshmallows.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet but security is much more than just a single encryption or transport method. Everything from where your computer was made, how it is configured, all the way to the intended receiver's practices and computer.

I believe the question is too broad and leads to too many opinions.